# Is a "transparent" macrolet possible?

Tags: macros, clojure, common-lisp

I'd like to write a Clojure `with-test-tags` macro that wraps a bunch of forms, and adds some metadata to the name of each `deftest` form - specifically, add some stuff to a `:tags` key, so that I can play with a tool to run tests with a specific tag.

One obvious implementation for `with-test-tags` is to walk the entire body recursively, modifying each `deftest` form as I find it. But I've been reading *Let Over Lambda* recently, and he makes a good point: instead of walking the code yourself, just wrap the code in a `macrolet` and let the compiler walk it for you. Something like:

```
(defmacro with-test-tags [tags & body]
  `(macrolet [(~'deftest [name# & more#]
                `(~'~'deftest ~(vary-meta name# update-in [:tags] (fnil into []) ~tags)
                   ~@more#))]
     (do ~@body)))

(with-test-tags [:a :b] 
  (deftest x (...do tests...)))
```

This has the obvious problem, though, that the `deftest` macro continues to expand recursively forever. I could make it expand to `clojure.test/deftest` instead, thus avoiding any further recursive expansions, but then I can't usefully nest instances of `with-test-tags` to label sub-groups of tests.

At this point, especially for something as simple as `deftest`, it looks like walking the code myself will be simpler. But I wonder if anyone knows a technique for writing a macro which "slightly modifies" certain subexpressions, without recursing forever.

For the curious: I considered some other approaches, such as having a compile-time `binding`-able var that I set as I go up and down the code, and using that var when I finally see a `deftest`, but since each macro only returns a single expansion its bindings won't be in place for the next call to macroexpand.

#### Edit

I did the postwalk implementation just now, and while it works it doesn't respect special forms such as `quote` - it expands inside of those as well.

```
(defmacro with-test-tags [tags & body]
  (cons `do
        (postwalk (fn [form]
                    (if (and (seq? form)
                             (symbol? (first form))
                             (= "deftest" (name (first form))))
                      (seq (update-in (vec form) [1]
                                      vary-meta update-in [:tags] (fnil into []) tags))
                      form))
                  body)))
```

(Also, sorry for possible noise on the common-lisp tag – I thought you might be able to help out with weirder macro stuff even with minimal Clojure experience.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*(This is a new approach, `eval`- and `binding`-free. As discussed in
the comments on this answer, the use of `eval` is problematic because
it prevents tests from closing over the lexical environments they seem
to be defined in (so `(let [x 1] (deftest easy (is (= x 1))))` no
longer works). I leave the original approach in the bottom half of the
answer, below the horizontal rule.)*

## The `macrolet` approach

### Implementation

Tested with Clojure 1.3.0-beta2; it should probably work with 1.2.x as
well.

```
(ns deftest-magic.core
  (:use [clojure.tools.macro :only [macrolet]]))

(defmacro with-test-tags [tags & body]
  (let [deftest-decl
        (list 'deftest ['name '& 'body]
              (list 'let ['n `(vary-meta ~'name update-in [:tags]
                                         (fnil into #{}) ~tags)
                          'form `(list* '~'clojure.test/deftest ~'n ~'body)]
                    'form))
        with-test-tags-decl
        (list 'with-test-tags ['tags '& 'body]
              `(list* '~'deftest-magic.core/with-test-tags
                      (into ~tags ~'tags) ~'body))]
    `(macrolet [~deftest-decl
                ~with-test-tags-decl]
       ~@body)))
```

### Usage

...is best demonstrated with a suite of (passing) tests:

```
(ns deftest-magic.test.core
  (:use [deftest-magic.core :only [with-test-tags]])
  (:use clojure.test))

;; defines a test with no tags attached:
(deftest plain-deftest
  (is (= :foo :foo)))

(with-test-tags #{:foo}

  ;; this test will be tagged #{:foo}:
  (deftest foo
    (is true))

  (with-test-tags #{:bar}

    ;; this test will be tagged #{:foo :bar}:
    (deftest foo-bar
      (is true))))

;; confirming the claims made in the comments above:
(deftest test-tags
  (let [plaintest-tags (:tags (meta #'plain-deftest))]
    (is (or (nil? plaintest-tags) (empty? plaintest-tags))))
  (is (= #{:foo} (:tags (meta #'foo))))
  (is (= #{:foo :bar} (:tags (meta #'foo-bar)))))

;; tests can be closures:
(let [x 1]
  (deftest lexical-bindings-no-tags
    (is (= x 1))))

;; this works inside with-test-args as well:
(with-test-tags #{:foo}
  (let [x 1]
    (deftest easy (is true))
    (deftest lexical-bindings-with-tags
      (is (= #{:foo} (:tags (meta #'easy))))
      (is (= x 1)))))
```

### Design notes:

1. We want to make the `macrolet`-based design described in the
   question text work. We care about being able to nest
   `with-test-tags` and preserving the possibility of defining tests
   whose bodies close over the lexical environments they are defined
   in.
2. We will be `macrolet`ting `deftest` to expand to a
   `clojure.test/deftest` form with appropriate metadata attached to
   the test's name. The important part here is that `with-test-tags`
   injects the appropriate tag set right into the definition of the
   custom local `deftest` inside the `macrolet` form; once the
   compiler gets around to expanding the `deftest` forms, the tag sets
   will have been hardwired into the code.
3. If we left it at that, tests defined inside a nested
   `with-test-tags` would only get tagged with the tags passed to the
   innermost `with-test-tags` form. Thus we have `with-test-tags` also
   `macrolet` the symbol `with-test-tags` itself behaving much like
   the local `deftest`: it expands to a call to the top-level
   `with-test-tags` macro with the appropriate tags injected into the
   tagset.
4. The intention is that the inner `with-test-tags` form in

   ```
   (with-test-tags #{:foo}
     (with-test-tags #{:bar}
       ...))
   ```

   expand to `(deftest-magic.core/with-test-tags #{:foo :bar} ...)`
   (if indeed `deftest-magic.core` is the namespace `with-test-tags`
   is defined in). This form immediately expands into the familiar
   `macrolet` form, with the `deftest` and `with-test-tags` symbols
   locally bound to macros with the correct tag sets hardwired inside
   them.

---

*(The original answer updated with some notes on the design, some
 rephrasing and reformatting etc. The code is unchanged.)*

## The `binding` + `eval` approach.

*(See also https://gist.github.com/1185513 for a version
 additionally using `macrolet` to avoid a custom top-level
 `deftest`.)*

### Implementation

The following is tested to work with Clojure 1.3.0-beta2; with the
`^:dynamic` part removed, it should work with 1.2:

```
(ns deftest-magic.core)

(def ^:dynamic *tags* #{})

(defmacro with-test-tags [tags & body]
  `(binding [*tags* (into *tags* ~tags)]
     ~@body))

(defmacro deftest [name & body]
  `(let [n# (vary-meta '~name update-in [:tags] (fnil into #{}) *tags*)
         form# (list* 'clojure.test/deftest n# '~body)]
     (eval form#)))
```

### Usage

```
(ns example.core
  (:use [clojure.test :exclude [deftest]])
  (:use [deftest-magic.core :only [with-test-tags deftest]]))

;; defines a test with an empty set of tags:
(deftest no-tags
  (is true))

(with-test-tags #{:foo}

  ;; this test will be tagged #{:foo}:
  (deftest foo
    (is true))

  (with-test-tags #{:bar}

    ;; this test will be tagged #{:foo :bar}:
    (deftest foo-bar
      (is true))))
```

### Design notes

I think that on this occasion a judicious use of `eval` leads to a
useful solution. The basic design (based on the "`binding`-able Var"
idea) has three components:

1. A dynamically bindable Var -- `*tags*` -- which is bound at compile
   time to a set of tags to be used by `deftest` forms to decorate the
   tests being defined. We add no tags by default, so its initial
   value is `#{}`.
2. A `with-test-tags` macro which installs an appropriate for
   `*tags*`.
3. A custom `deftest` macro which expands to a `let` form resembling
   this (the following is the expansion, slightly simplified for
   clarity):

   ```
   (let [n    (vary-meta '<NAME> update-in [:tags] (fnil into #{}) *tags*)
         form (list* 'clojure.test/deftest n '<BODY>)]
     (eval form))
   ```

   `<NAME>` and `<BODY>` are the arguments given to the custom
   `deftest`, inserted in the appropriate spots through unquoting the
   appropriate parts of the syntax-quoted expansion template.

Thus the expansion of the custom `deftest` is a `let` form in which,
first, the name of the new test is prepared by decorating the given
symbol with the `:tags` metadata; then a `clojure.test/deftest` form
using this decorated name is constructed; and finally the latter form
is handed to `eval`.

The key point here is that the `(eval form)` expressions here are
evaluated whenever the namespace their contained in is AOT-compiled or
required *for the first time* in the lifetime of the JVM running this
code. This is exactly the same as the `(println "asdf")` in a
top-level `(def asdf (println "asdf"))`, which will print `asdf`
whenever the namespace is AOT-compiled or required *for the first
time*; in fact, a top-level `(println "asdf")` acts similarly.

This is explained by noting that compilation, in Clojure, is just
evaluation of all top-level forms. In `(binding [...] (deftest ...)`,
`binding` is the top-level form, but it only returns when `deftest`
does, and our custom `deftest` expands to a form which returns when
`eval` does. (On the other hand, the way `require` executes top-level
code in already-compiled namespaces -- so that if you have `(def t
(System/currentTimeMillis))` in your code, the value of `t` will
depend on when you require your namespace rather than on when it was
compiled, as can be determined by experimenting with AOT-compiled code
-- is just the way Clojure works. Use read-eval if you want actual
constants embedded in code.)

In effect, the custom `deftest` runs the compiler (through `eval`) at
the run-time-at-compile-time of macro expansion. Fun.

Finally, when a `deftest` form is put inside a `with-test-tags` form,
the `form` of `(eval form)` will have been prepared with the bindings
installed by `with-test-tags` in place. Thus the test being defined
will be decorated with the appropriate set of tags.

### At the REPL

```
user=> (use 'deftest-magic.core '[clojure.test :exclude [deftest]])
nil
user=> (with-test-tags #{:foo}
         (deftest foo (is true))
         (with-test-tags #{:bar}
           (deftest foo-bar (is true))))
#'user/foo-bar
user=> (meta #'foo)
{:ns #<Namespace user>,
 :name foo,
 :file "NO_SOURCE_PATH",
 :line 2,
 :test #<user$fn__90 user$fn__90@50903025>,
 :tags #{:foo}}                                         ; <= note the tags
user=> (meta #'foo-bar)
{:ns #<Namespace user>,
 :name foo-bar,
 :file "NO_SOURCE_PATH",
 :line 2,
 :test #<user$fn__94 user$fn__94@368b1a4f>,
 :tags #{:foo :bar}}                                    ; <= likewise
user=> (deftest quux (is true))
#'user/quux
user=> (meta #'quux)
{:ns #<Namespace user>,
 :name quux,
 :file "NO_SOURCE_PATH",
 :line 5,
 :test #<user$fn__106 user$fn__106@b7c96a9>,
 :tags #{}}                                             ; <= no tags works too
```

And just to be sure working tests are being defined...

```
user=> (run-tests 'user)

Testing user

Ran 3 tests containing 3 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
{:type :summary, :pass 3, :test 3, :error 0, :fail 0}
```

Comment: Very interesting. It is hard to imagine a valid use case for `eval` at compile time, but this one makes some sense. A couple issues: (1) is there a way to do this with `macrolet` so that the user only needs to refer to `with-test-tags`, without creating a conflicting `deftest` reference? (2) This means that `deftest` forms can't be lexical closures, like `(let [x 1] (deftest ...))`, which is somewhat unfortunate. Do you see any way around that?

Comment: To clarify the above: I tried to port your solution to use `macrolet`, but having to work with the *three* different levels of quoting and different execution times was just too much for me.

Comment: Sure, it can be done with macrolet. [Here is the Gist of it.](https://gist.github.com/1185513) I'll post it here later, but for now, the Gist contains a minimal working project with a version of `with-test-tags` based on `macrolet` (the one from `tools.macro`) and a handful of tests. The usage is unchanged, except client code uses the standard `deftest`. Thankfully, the definition of the custom `deftest` can be injected straight into the `macrolet` with the appropriate `~'`. :-)

Comment: As for (2), agreed that this is unfortunate. I will think about this some more; the one somewhat promising approach that I see seems to have a glaring problem, but I'll try it out anyway...

Comment: Ok, I have an `eval`- and `binding`-free solution which passes all the tests written for the previous versions plus a new test to verify that tests can be closures and be tagged at the same time. [The Gist is here.](https://gist.github.com/1187328) I'll post it here too in a little while, together with a small summary of the design.

Comment: A cleaned up version of the `macrolet` solution is now part of [flatland](http://flatland.org/)'s [`useful`](http://github.com/flatland/useful) project, see https://github.com/flatland/useful/commit/3da414e8a57d49e4fdd02594d667307bcefef040. @amalloy: thanks for pulling this in!

Answer (score 0):

With Common Lisp at least, you simply alias the shadowed macro. Something like:

```
(setf (macro-function 'deftest2) (macro-function 'deftest))
(defmacro with-test-tags (etc...)
  `(macrolet ((deftest (etc...)
                 ``(deftest2 ...
```

Clojure should have something similar. The topic is discussed here: [define a synonym for a Clojure macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317396/define-a-synonym-for-a-clojure-macro). Be aware that defining a 'deftest2' macro that expands to a 'deftest' call probably won't work.

I see that this answer is a little late, but I'll post it here for passers by.