# How to create configurable macros

Tags: clojure, macros

Suppose that we want to write a macro whose behavior depends on some kind of configuration. Specifically, in my case the configuration is just a boolean value indicating some optimization in the output code. Even more specifically, the transformation looks like this (denoting macroexpansion by `==>`):

```clj
(transform ...) ==> (transform'-opt ...) ==> (transform' ...) ==> ...
```

when the optimization takes place, otherwise `transform'-opt` is omitted and `transform'` is used in its place.

Using a parameter for the configuration would result in too much repetition, so it would be preferable to configure the macro in a local/`with-...` style  (and possibly in a global style too). By this I mean that, using something like `(with-opt value expr*)`, during the macroexpansion of each `expr` `value` is used as the configuration of `transform` unless this is changed by another `with-opt`. The solution I have chosen so far is to use a dynamic var and `binding` in the following way:

```clj
(require '[clojure.tools.analyzer.jvm :refer [macroexpand-all]])

(def ^:dynamic *opt* true)

(defmacro with-opt [value & body]
  `(do ~@(binding [*opt* value] (mapv macroexpand-all body))))

(defmacro transform [...]
  `(~(if *opt* `transform'-opt `transform') ...))
```

However, the use of dynamic vars and `macroexpand-all` at macroexpansion looks somewhat unconventional to me. Other (also unconventional) options I have considered include using a regular var and `with-redefs`, an atom, a volatile and also hiding the configuration inside closures like this:

```clj
(let [opt ...]
  (defmacro with-opt ...)
  (defmacro transform ...))
```

[Perhaps an imaginary generic way to avoid mutation and manual macroexpansion in such cases could be to introduce another implicit `&config` parameter in macros and a new special form `(with-macro-configs [(macro config)*] expr*)` that would specify the value used for this parameter for various macros.]

Is there any common practice for such a situation? What would your approach be and why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add a more concrete example of a problem you are trying to solve and how this would be used?  Also, what would the config options be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the kind of thing that is difficult to do with Clojure's macro system, but would be easy if we had `macrolet`. I recall reading, I think in Let Over Lambda, that most code-walking macros that attempt to walk code themselves would be made much simpler and more robust by using `macrolet` (which does exist in other Lisp dialects). That way, the compiler does all the difficult work for you, including handling shadowing and quoting correctly, etc.

For a simple example, suppose you have some macro that needs a boolean parameter, and you wish within a lexical context to have that always be `true`. With `macrolet`, you could write:

```
(defmacro change* [code toggle]
  (if toggle
    `(not ~code)
    code))

(defmacro with-toggle [toggle & body]
  `(macrolet [(~'change [code#]
                `(change* ~code# ~~toggle))]
     ~@body))

(with-toggle true
  (change (= 1 2)))
```

While `macrolet` does not exist in the Clojure standard library, there is an implementation in `clojure.tools.macro` that is *almost* as good as one built into the compiler would be. There are a few edge cases it does not support, but for every reasonable macro I've ever wanted to write it has been correct. Here is evidence that it works for our example case:

```
user=> (macroexpand '(with-toggle false (change (= 1 2))))
(do (= 1 2))
user=> (macroexpand '(with-toggle true (change (= 1 2))))
(do (clojure.core/not (= 1 2)))
```

Of course the difficult part is writing the body of the `macrolet`, because you have to deal with two levels of syntax quoting. I supposedly know what I'm doing, but I still took three or four tries to get this simple macro right. Just remember that each `~` escapes a single level of syntax-quoting, after which you have to decide what to do next: escape again, use a `gensym#` variable, use a normal quote, or just stay a single level deep.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if `change` is surrounded by more than one `with-toggle`, e.g. `(with-toggle true (with-toggle false (change (= 1 2))))`, would it be possible to take *all* values from the surrounding scopes into account, e.g. combining them with `or` (*which would be possible with my approach*)?

Comment: I'm not expert enough with this technique to say I have the best approach, but it's hard to define macros that shadow themselves. The best I can think of, if you want a value like this, is to use `symbol-macrolet` instead. Each new use of `with-toggle` can copy the existing binding to a gensymmed name, then shadow the old binding with a new one that refers to the gensym. So instead of modifying `change`, we introduce and modify a named variable that represents its implicit first parameter.

Comment: @Rulle Actually, it turns out this is a question I asked on SO myself 9 years ago. I got a good answer, but clearly didn't internalize it well enough to repeat it here! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240947/is-a-transparent-macrolet-possible

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. I didn't know about `macrolet` and it looks like a nice alternative (with its own peculiarities of course). Interestingly, [the source of `clojure.tools.macro`](https://github.com/clojure/tools.macro/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/tools/macro.clj) uses a `binding`+`macroexpand-all` trick like the one in my solution.

Comment: Yeah, since it's outside the compiler that's about the best it can do. If it were inside the compiler it would just use the existing mechanism for variable bindings in `let`.

Answer (score 2):

A macro transforms code, represented as a datastructure, to another datastructure. I would write a macro that transforms the code using [postwalk](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/postwalk) and inserts the parameter for a specified form as last argument every time it encounters it. You could have a macro `with-arg` that will do the transformation:

```
(require '[clojure.walk :refer [postwalk]])

(defmacro with-arg [[sym arg] & body]
  `(do ~@(postwalk #(if (and (seq? %)
                             (= sym (first %)))
                      (concat % [arg])
                      %)
                   body)))
```

Suppose we have some macro that will do the code transformation and that we can pass it options. Just to demonstrate, here is dummy macro for that to test things out:

```
(defmacro transform [x & optimization-options]
  `(println ~x ~(into [] cat optimization-options)))
```

and here is an example using it:

```
(do
  (println "No optimizations enabled")
  (transform :X)
  (with-arg [transform [:unroll]]
    (println "With unrolling")
    (transform :Y)
    (with-arg [transform [:inline :O3]]
      (println "With some extra options")
      (transform :Z))))
```

which will print

```
No optimizations enabled
:X []
With unrolling
:Y [:unroll]
With some extra options
:Z [:unroll :inline :O3]
```

In the code example, we only call `transform` with a *single* argument, but the macro transformations make it receive the options from *all* the surrounding `with-arg` forms. We can then decide how we combine all the options, e.g. using `(into [] cat optimization-options)`. Or we could do `(last optimization-options)` if we want the innermost `with-arg` to shadow the outer ones.

One issue with this approach is that it may not compose well with other macros, such as `->`. For example, this code:

```
(with-arg [transform [:unroll]]
  (-> :X0
      transform))

(with-arg [transform [:unroll]]
  (-> :X1
      (transform)))
```

will print this:

```
:X0 []
:X1 [:unroll]
```

But this might not be a problem in practice, as long as you are aware of it.

Comment: This is a reasonable try, but in addition to the problem you mention it doesn't account for quoting (e.g. `(with-arg [f 1] (cons (f) '(f g h))`) or shadowing (`(with-arg [f 1] (... (with-arg [f 2] ...)))`).

Comment: Though on reflection I'm not sure what shadowing is supposed to do in this case, since we're not defining a new `f`, but refining an existing one. So I suppose your implementation is as good as any, as far as shadowing goes.

Comment: @amalloy I am not sure the OP actually would want to make this work for quoted expressions. Maybe it isn't even desirable. As for shadowing, see updated answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, "isn't even desirable". Surely it's not desirable for `with-arg` to descend into quoted expressions and rewrite them as if they were going to be evaluated?

Comment: What kind of computation does the code `(with-arg [f 1] (cons (f) '(f g h)))` represent and why would you write that code? If you are specific about that, we can discuss whether or not it is desirable for `with-arg` to descend into the quoted expression.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice try but problems with macroexpansion and quoting like the ones you and amalloy noticed make it unacceptable as a solution. This type of code-walking is just a little "shallow" and, in the absence of built-in constructs like `macrolet` or my imaginary `with-macro-configs`, manual full macroexpansion seems unavoidable. As for shadowing, it is supposed to happen (this is what I meant writing "unless this is changed by another `with-opt`") and, in general, the expected behavior is that of the solution I presented in the question.