# Clojure Metaprogramming Question (for a beginner!)

Tags: clojure

All, I'm starting to take a look at the Clojure language, and had a couple questions about something I'm trying to do. The broad objective is to alias the sequence function `every?` to `all?`. I'm sure there's a function or macro that does alias-ing (or something along those lines) but I wanted to see if it was possible with some of the basic constructs I know thus far. My approach was going to be to define a function called `all?` that applies its arguments to the `every?` implementation.

I'm curious to see if this can be made agnostic, so I wanted to parameter my alias function to take two arguments, the new name (as a Keyword) and the old name (as a function reference). In striving towards this goal, I've encountered two problems.

1) Defining named functions with Keywords throws errors. Apparently it wants `clojure.lang.IObj`.

```
user=> (defn :foo "bar")     
java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.Keyword cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IObj (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

Is there a function to cast a Keyword to an IObj, or other means to parameterize the name of a newly defined function with some provided value? (In Ruby, define_method amongst other techniques does this)

```
irb(main)> self.class.instance_eval do
irb(main)* define_method(:foo) { "bar" }
irb(main)> end
=> #<Proc>
irb(main)> foo
=> "bar"
```

2) Collect all arguments to a function into a single variable. Even basic functions such as `(+ 1 2 3 4)` take a variable amount of arguments. All the function definition techniques I've seen so far take a specific amount of arguments, with no way to just aggregate everything in a list for handling in the function body. Once again, what I'm going for is done in Ruby like so:

```
irb(main)> def foo(*args)
irb(main)> p args
irb(main)> end
=> nil
irb(main)> foo(1, 2, 3)
[1, 2, 3]
=> nil
```

Thanks for any help you can provide me!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'll answer in bullet points, since the questions can be split neatly into a number of separate issues.

- Something which is implicitly contained in what is to follow, but which perhaps warrants a bullet of its own: the top-level objects created by `def` & Co. (and in particular by `defn`) are Vars. So what you actually want to do is to alias a *Var*; functions are just regular values which don't really have names (except they may have a name bound to themselves locally inside their bodies; that's nothing to do with the issue at hand, though).
- There is indeed an "aliasing macro" available in Clojure -- `clojure.contrib.def/defalias`:

  ```
  (use '[clojure.contrib.def :only [defalias]])
  (defalias foo bar)
  ; => foo can now be used in place of bar
  ```

  The advantage of this over `(def foo bar)` is that it copies over metadata (such as the docstring); it even appears to work with macros in the current HEAD, although I recall a bug which prevented that in earlier versions.
- Vars are named by symbols, not keywords. Symbol literals in Clojure (and other Lisps) do not start with colons (`:foo` is a keyword, not a symbol). Thus to define a function called `foo` you should write

  ```
  (defn foo [...] ...)
  ```
- `defn` is a helper macro easing the creation of *new* function-holding Vars by allowing the programmer to use a mix of `def` & `fn` syntax. So `defn` is out of question for creating Vars with preexisting values (which might be functions), as is required for creating aliases; use `defalias` or simply `def` instead.
- To create a variadic function, use the following syntax:

  ```
  (fn [x y & args] ...)
  ```

  `x` and `y` will be required positional arguments; the rest of the arguments passed to the function (any number of them) will be collected into a seq and available under the name `args`. You don't have to specify any "required positional arguments" if they are not needed: `(fn [& args] ...)`.

  To create a Var holding a variadic function, use

  ```
  (defn foo [x y & args] ...)
  ```
- To apply a function to some arguments you've got assembled into a seqable object (such as the `args` seq in the above examples or perhaps a vector &c.), use `apply`:

  ```
  (defn all? [& args]
    (apply every? args))
  ```
- If you want to write a *function* to create aliases -- as opposed to a macro -- you'll need to investigate the functions `intern`, `with-meta`, `meta` -- and possibly `resolve` / `ns-resolve`, depending on whether the function is to accept symbols or Vars. I'll leave filling in the details as an exercise to the reader. :-)

Comment: Just posted a Gist with an `intern-alias` function realising the design hinted at in the last paragraph. I'll add a docstring in a second. It copies the meta from the original to the alias, supports creating aliases in namespaces other than the current one, accepts both symbols and Vars as the originals &c. See http://gist.github.com/464970

Comment: Come on, dude. At least give other people a chance! Isn't there some sort of drug you can take to lower your intelligence level back to *normal*? Come back to us, bro, we miss you. :p

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth comment. It definitely illuminated most all of what I was looking for. With regards to point #3 (vars are named by symbols, not keywords), is there a way to case a keyword into a symbol? Say, for the sake of an exercise I wanted to write a function that wrapped def, and took two arguments, a keyword and a value, and then internally called def and named the variable the keyword's name. Possible?

Comment: @Evan: You can't do it with `def` without using `eval`, because `def` needs a literal symbol as its first argument. Better use `intern` (which provides the functionality of `def` packaged as a function, meaning in particular that it evaluates its arguments, so you can say `(intern *ns* (symbol (name :foo)) initial-value)`). As for keyword <-> symbol coercion, you can create symbols from strings with the function `symbol`, obtain the name of a keyword/symbol with the function `name` and create keywords from strings and symbols with the function `keyword`; see `(doc symbol)` &c. for details.

Comment: @Rayne: Thank you for your very kind overthetopism. I shall strive to become deserving of it. :-)

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do is bind the every? function to the all? symbol, which is done via def:

```
(def all? every?)
```

For a bit more on this, see [Clojure macro to create a synonym for a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315099/clojure-macro-to-create-a-synonym-for-a-function/1315233#1315233)

Comment: I was exploring the implementation of a feature like this, but I'm glad to know the quick way to do it too, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Don't think I can add much to the existing explanations here, except perhaps fill out a couple of blanks in the Ruby traveller's dictionary on argument collection and destructuring:

```
(defn foo [& args]                 ; Ruby: def foo(*args)
  (println args))    
user=> (foo 1 2 3)
(1 2 3)

(defn foo [& args] 
  (+ args))   
user=> (foo 1 2 3)
java.lang.ClassCastException       ; + takes numbers, not a list

(defn foo [& args] 
  (apply + args))                  ; apply: as Ruby proc.call(*args)
user=> (foo 1 2 3)
6

(defn foo [& args]
  (let [[a b & other] args]        ; Ruby: a, b, *other = args
    (println a b other)))
user=> (foo 1 2 3)
1 2 (3)
```